# SQL property from inherited Parent-Child relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Your inputs would be greatly appreciated..!! Please have a look and suggest..

Two Tables -

**Table1**

```
User(PK) | Permission_On
usr1     | Folder_A
usr2     | Folder_B
usr3     | Folder_C
```

and

**Table2**

```
RowAddedTimeStamp(PK) | User(PK) | Substitute_User | BeginDate | EndDate
xxxx1                 | usr1     | usr1            | 1-1-2010  | 1-1-2010
xxxx2                 | usr2     | usr2            | 1-1-2010  | 1-1-2010
xxxx3                 | usr1     | usr2            | 1-1-2010  | 1-1-2012
xxxx4                 | usr3     | usr3            | 1-1-2010  | 1-1-2010
xxxx5                 | usr2     | usr3            | 1-1-2011  | 1-1-2013
```

**I have tried but not getting how to get the exact permission on particular user with consideration of Substitute user.**

Like if today is -

**2-2-2011**   Permission on **usr3** would be -  **Folder_A, Folder_B, Folder_C**

```
Folder_C  -- Direct permission for usr3
Folder_B  -- as usr3 is substitute of usr2 (between 1-1-2011  to 1-1-2013)
Folder_A  -- as usr2 is substitute of usr1 (between 1-1-2010  to 1-1-2012)
```

**2-2-2012**   Permission on **usr3** would be - **Folder_B, Folder_C**

```
Folder_C  -- Direct permission for usr3
Folder_B  -- as usr3 is substitute of usr2 (between 1-1-2011  to 1-1-2013)
Folder_A  -- **** NO because usr2 was substitute of usr1 (between 1-1-2010  to 1-1-2012) and today is 2-2-2012
```

**2-2-2013**   Permission on **usr3** would be -  **Folder_C**

```
Folder_C  -- Direct permission for usr3
Folder_B  -- **** NO because usr3 was substitute of usr2 (between 1-1-2011  to 1-1-2013)  and today is 2-2-2013
Folder_A  -- **** NO because usr2 was substitute of usr1 (between 1-1-2010  to 1-1-2012) and today is 2-2-2013
```

Comment: Are you reall using MySQL **and** SQL Server **and** Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sql Server.  Not Oracle and MySql.   But as suggested and query gonna be same in case of Oracle and MySql So tag these two as well..

Comment: Given the limited features of MySQL (especially for recursive queries), I very much doubt that the same query can be used for SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL for this problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am agreed each and every query not gonna be same in MySql And SQL Server and Oracle.  well I am talking about Sql Server 2008r2 and might be need the same in Oracle as well as having the same product with Sql Server and Oracle both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a MSSQL functions. It will drastically improve performance comparing to nested and recursive queries.

e.g. Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getUserList (@inputUser VARCHAR(250), @inputDate VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS @UserList TABLE
   (
    userName   varchar(250),
   )
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT @UserList
        SELECT a.Substitute_User,
        FROM Table2 AS a
        WHERE a.User = @inputUser
        AND a.BeginDate <= @inputDate
        AND a.EndDate >= @inputDate
   RETURN
END
```

And afterwards use it as a source as substitute user list e.g.

```
SELECT Permission_On FROM Table1 WHERE
User IN (SELECT userName FROM Table1('usr1','2-2-2011'))
OR User = 'usr1'
```

**--Edit--**

Ohh, I see, I misunderstood the user with the Substitute user..
In such case you can use SQL CTE functionality:

Take a look at this 
[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfe88/11)

In this query you should replace the User and both the dates in the query

```
WITH AccessHierarchy ( Userr ) AS
(
   -- Base case
   SELECT
      Userr
   FROM Table1
   WHERE Userr = 'usr3'

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
   SELECT
      e.Userr
   FROM Table2 e
      INNER JOIN AccessHierarchy eh ON
         e.Substitute_User = eh.Userr
      WHERE e.Userr != e.Substitute_User
      AND BeginDate <= '2011-05-05'
      AND EndDate >= '2011-05-05'
)

SELECT Permission_On FROM Table1
WHERE Userr IN
(Select Userr
FROM AccessHierarchy
)
```

And you can create test tables with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
    (
     Userr VARCHAR(255) primary key, 
     Permission_On varchar(255)
    );

INSERT INTO Table1
(Userr, Permission_On)
VALUES
('usr1', 'folA'),
('usr2', 'folB'),
('usr3', 'folC');



CREATE TABLE Table2
    (
     Userr VARCHAR(255), 
     Substitute_User varchar(255), 
     BeginDate DATETIME, 
     EndDate DATETIME, 
    );

INSERT INTO Table2
(Userr, Substitute_User, BeginDate, EndDate)
VALUES
('usr1', 'usr1', '2010-01-01', '2010-01-01'),
('usr2', 'usr2', '2010-01-01', '2010-01-01'),
('usr1', 'usr2', '2010-01-01', '2012-01-01'),
('usr3', 'usr3', '2010-01-01', '2010-01-01'),
('usr2', 'usr3', '2011-01-01', '2013-01-01');
```

Comment: can you please tell me what u r doing?? what first function will return and what this query doing?? did u try to run above both together?  I think in query wanted to use getUserList instead of **table1**.. right? and did u try to run that function u designed? I gave the example so that people can test their **"I suppose" and "I think"**

Comment: try to run ur function against my first input.. **usr3 and 2-2-2011** i will return usr2 and usr3, but it should return all three.. I think now you can get it..

Comment: The function above gets the substitute user list for a selected user at appropriate date. Afterwards you can get list of folders you can access by a simple query - get all folders where accessUser  is active user or someone from retrieved substitute list

Comment: did u try to run the above method?? no..!! i thnk it has the syntax error and even if u remove that error still it will return only usr3 for **getUserList('usr3', '2-2-2011')** and you can not compare the string as date in your function.. it has lot of error.. Far away from answer..

Comment: Have run it on my old MSSQL server with according field names and it works fine :)

Designed logics with current database for query call getUserList('usr3', '2-2-2011') should return NULL as usr 3 ONLY substitutes himself (usr3) on 1-1-2010 :)

Comment: right.. i mean for usr3 no result.. but for the given input it should return all 3 users right?

Comment: Now I get it. My bad, mistook the User and Substitute User columns.
Take a look at edited solution in SQLFiddle

Comment: right.. CTE is the option.. I also found the same solution .. :)

Comment: I think in fiddle you have the order by which is creating problem. while the code u pasted here doesn't have the order by so that is okay.. so better to modify the fiddle link